# Moving unallocated space to another disk in RAID 10

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dell-openmanage

Can anyone help me with this? I need to increase the size of Virtual Disk 1. Is it possible to remove Virtual Disk 2 (which is blank) and add that space to Virtual Disk 1? Virtual Disk 1 is using MBR and hosting a VHDX.
If so could anyone please give me advice on how to do this? 
[image: Dell OpenManage]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7FzT.png

Comment: It looks like your volumes are limited by a 2tb boundary. That’s the maximum your mbr drives can handle. You could probably delete the empty virtual volume and expand the first volume. But you would have to convert your drive to GPT and have a BIOS capable of booting UEFI to use the space. There are also no native tools in server 2012 to do this, so you have to rely on a 3rd party and potentially destructive process to do this. The only “supported” method is to wipe the drive and start over.

Comment: Is there any way to get the full 2TB, or actually I just need 1.82TB so it has enough room for a VHDX that will soon expand to that size. The drive in the OS only shows 1.79 TB.

Comment: There are a lot of potential limitations here. It could be the Perc H730, could be the OS, the partition style, etc. I’m assuming the size you currently have is the maximum per volume. And there may no way to go larger with your hardware. All you can do is delete the unused volume and see if it gives any errors or warning about expanding the existing volume. Just don’t complete the expansion until you are ready. Even if you expanded it, it shouldn’t break anything, the OS just wont be able to use it.